# STM32F4: How to get data from multiple channels sampled from a single ADC?

Tags: adc, timer, stm32f4, trigger, stm32cubemx

So I have searched everywhere for a solution to this problem but I can find anything. I have three channels connected to `ADC1` of my STM32F446ZE-nucleo and I want to sample the channels at a rate of 200 Hz each. I set up `TIM2` and linked it as the interrupt for the ADC conversion, and this works fine for 1 channel. But I am struggling to get it to work for multiple channels since I don't know how to get the data from each specific channel within the `HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback`.

My setup looks like this:

```
/* ADC1 init function */
static void MX_ADC1_Init(void)
{

  ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig;

    /**Configure the global features of the ADC (Clock, Resolution, Data Alignment and number of conversion) 
    */
  hadc1.Instance = ADC1;
  hadc1.Init.ClockPrescaler = ADC_CLOCK_SYNC_PCLK_DIV4;
  hadc1.Init.Resolution = ADC_RESOLUTION_12B;
  hadc1.Init.ScanConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ContinuousConvMode = ENABLE;
  hadc1.Init.DiscontinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONVEDGE_RISING;
  hadc1.Init.ExternalTrigConv = ADC_EXTERNALTRIGCONV_T2_TRGO;
  hadc1.Init.DataAlign = ADC_DATAALIGN_RIGHT;
  hadc1.Init.NbrOfConversion = 3;
  hadc1.Init.DMAContinuousRequests = DISABLE;
  hadc1.Init.EOCSelection = ADC_EOC_SEQ_CONV;
  if (HAL_ADC_Init(&hadc1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
  sConfig.Rank = 1;
  sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLETIME_15CYCLES;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
  sConfig.Rank = 2;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time. 
    */
  sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_2;
  sConfig.Rank = 3;
  if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* TIM2 init function */
static void MX_TIM2_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig;
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig;

  htim2.Instance = TIM2;
  htim2.Init.Prescaler = 41999;
  htim2.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim2.Init.Period = 4;
  htim2.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim2, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_UPDATE;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim2, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}
```

I start my `ADC` and timer after receiving data on `USART3` like this:

```
// start timer and ADC interrupt
HAL_ADC_Start_IT(&hadc1);
HAL_TIM_Base_Start(&htim2);
```

This is where I am struggling to get the right data:

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef* hadc)
{

    // get values
    WE_ADC_VAL = HAL_ADC_GetValue(hadc);

    uint32_t nrConv = hadc->NbrOfCurrentConversionRank;

    // populate buffer
    transmitBuf[0] = WE_ADC_VAL >> 8; // upper 8 bits
    transmitBuf[1] = WE_ADC_VAL & 0x00FF; // lower 8 bits

    // send by interrupt mode
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart3, transmitBuf, 2);
}
```

I thought that `hadc->NbrOfCurrentConversionRank` should have info on which channel is being sampled, but it is constantly 0 (I thought it would go from 1 to 2 to 3). How would I go about to get the individual channel's data at each conversion complete interrupt? Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Ask a specific question, you'll get better answers.

Comment: I am struggling with the same problem. Did you solve it? if this is the case how did you proceed? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a comment to ask you if you want my solution, which includes 3 ADCs x 3 Channels = 9 signals, by utilizing DMA peripheral and no HAL libraries. Since my rep is < 50, I cannot make that comment, so I will provide the code for the above :P

It utilizes a Master-Slave technique, with ADC1 set as the master and ADC2 and 3 as slaves. Interrupts occur based on TIM2 frequency, which can be modified.

Hope it helps :)

---

μC Board: STM32F429ZI-Discovery

IDE: μVision V5.13.0.0

[image]

TIM2 Enable

```
#define ADC_PER 4499

RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM2, ENABLE);

TIM_BaseStruct_ST.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
TIM_BaseStruct_ST.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
// 899 => 100kHz, 2249 => 40kHz, 4499 => 20kHz, 8999 => 10kHz
TIM_BaseStruct_ST.TIM_Period = ADC_PER; 
TIM_BaseStruct_ST.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;

TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_BaseStruct_ST);
TIM_SelectOutputTrigger(TIM2, TIM_TRGOSource_Update);
```

ADC Clock Enable

```
#include "stm32f4xx_adc.h"
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd (RCC_APB2Periph_ADC1, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd (RCC_APB2Periph_ADC2, ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd (RCC_APB2Periph_ADC3, ENABLE);
```

ADC set to Triple Mode, DMA Enable, No Prescaler

```
ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStructure;

ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Mode          = ADC_TripleMode_RegSimult;
ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_Prescaler     = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
ADC_CommonInitStructure.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_1;
ADC_CommonInit (&ADC_CommonInitStructure);
```

3 conversions for each ADC, hence 9 in total.
Highest resolution of 12 bits, right data alignment and event trigger by TIM2 interrupts.

```
ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStructure;

ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ScanConvMode       = ENABLE;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_NbrOfConversion    = 3;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_Resolution         = ADC_Resolution_12b;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_DataAlign          = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;

TIM_SelectOutputTrigger (TIM2, TIM_TRGOSource_Update);
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConv     = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T2_TRGO;
ADC_InitStructure.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_Rising;

ADC_Init(ADC1, &ADC_InitStructure);
ADC_Init(ADC2, &ADC_InitStructure);
ADC_Init(ADC3, &ADC_InitStructure);
```

Set each channel to the right pin, with 15 cycles for sampling the signal

```
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC1, ADC_Channel_13, 1, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC1, ADC_Channel_8,  2, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC1, ADC_Channel_6,  3, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);

ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC2, ADC_Channel_0,  1, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC2, ADC_Channel_10, 2, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC2, ADC_Channel_14, 3, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);

ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC3, ADC_Channel_15, 1, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC3, ADC_Channel_9,  2, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
ADC_RegularChannelConfig (ADC3, ADC_Channel_3,  3, ADC_SampleTime_15Cycles);
```

DMA Clock Enable.

Setup DMA data transport, base address, matrix size, half word data transfer and circular mode.

Enable Stream4 of DMA2.

```
#include "stm32f4xx_dma.h"
RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);

DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR     = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_0;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&ADC->CDR;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc      = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr    = (uint32_t)(&adc[0]);
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc          = DMA_MemoryInc_Enable;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 9;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize     = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord;

DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Circular;

DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream4, &DMA_InitStructure)
```

Setup and enable interrupt event of DMA

```
NVIC_InitTypeDef ADCNVICConfig;
ADCNVICConfig.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Stream4_IRQn;
ADCNVICConfig.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
ADCNVICConfig.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 1;
ADCNVICConfig.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&ADCNVICConfig);

ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
ADC_MultiModeDMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ENABLE);
DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream4, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);

DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream4, ENABLE);
```

Setup ADC1 as Master and ADC2 and ADC3 as Slaves, enable DMA and all ADCs.

```
ADC_DMACmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
ADC_MultiModeDMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ENABLE);

ADC_Cmd(ADC1, ENABLE);
ADC_Cmd(ADC2, ENABLE);
ADC_Cmd(ADC3, ENABLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done almost without writing any code.

Go to Cube configuration and setup ADC for continuous scan conversion with DMA. Set "number of conversions" to how many channels you want to sample. This will create as many "Ranks", or slots for your channels.

[image]

For every Rank configure which channel you want to sample and for how long. You need to consult reference manual to find out how to calculate sampling time for desired precision and given source impedance. The combined time will define your data rate, so some compromise may be required.

[image]

Finally, go to DMA settings, select circular mode and 2-byte data size. Note that in some Cube versions you have to configure circular DMA first, before continuous conversion option becomes available in ADC settings.

[image]

Now, all you have to do is create a buffer to receive data from DMA and start conversions:

```
static uint16_t dmaBuffer[5];
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA((&hadc1, (uint32_t*)&dmaBuffer, 5);
```

After that, whenever you need ADC value from some channel you simply get it from this buffer at corresponding index. For example, if you want channel 6 and you configured it at rank 3 then you get the value like this:

```
uint16_t ch6 = dmaBuffer[2];
```

Literally 3 lines of code. I do not count Cube-generated code here, of course. Surprisingly, the HAL overhead is not as huge for ADC handling as it is for most of the hardware.